# openCV video not registering final frame

Tags: c++, opencv

I am displaying and manipulating a video with open CV as so

```
// looping through list of videos
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < img_loc.size(); i++)
{
    string fileLoc = root_dir + "\\" + img_loc[i];


    string name = img_loc[i].substr(0,img_loc[i].find("."));
    cv::VideoCapture cap(fileLoc);
    image_window win;

    int cnt = 0;


    while (!win.is_closed())
    {
        cv::Mat temp;
        cap >> temp;

        if (temp.empty())
        {
            break;
        }

        cout << "frame number ---- " << cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) << endl;

        cv_image<bgr_pixel> cimg(temp);

        // some image manipulations

        win.clear_overlay();
        win.set_image(cimg);

        cout << cnt << endl;

        // save some details

        cnt++;

        cout << "after cnt++ ------------ " << cnt << endl;

    }


    cout << endl << "finished with " << img_loc[i] << ", proceed to the next video?" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

which works fine for the first for all frames except the very last. I know there are exactly 200 frames but cnt only ever reaches 198 and the frames only ever go up to 199. The final frame isn't entirely necessary but it means there's some extra data handling that I'd rather avoid. Any ideas?

Comment: So it is reaching frame # 199? Your code is 0-indexed, so the 200th frame has i == 199

Comment: no the count "cnt" is reaching 198 and the number of frame number, 1-indexed, only reaches 199

Comment: What version of opencv are you using? all your code appears to be 0 indexed. (And I am fairly certain opencv 0-indexes frames in video.)

Comment: i got to the bottom of it, thankfully it wasn't an indexing issue. for some unknown reason the videos were only 199 frames long even though the specs had information for 200 frames. Its not clear if the first or last frame is missing but that can be smoothed out.

Comment: Ok, glad you got it figured out.